# compiler is always printing a hexadecimal/octal number

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, c++17

I was just beginning to learn about references in C++, and i tried the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        int ival = 1024;
        int &refVal = ival;
        // refVal refers to (is another name for) ival
        cout<< &refVal<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Where the output of this program is:

```
0x61feb8
```

I don't know what it is?
Please also elaborate if you feel i am lacking some basic/very important knowledge here!

Edit: Thanks to everyone for explanation! Sorry for too silly question!

Comment: What are you trying to do? `&refVal` takes the memory address of `refVal` … that's what you're printing.

Comment: cout<< &refVal is the adress of refVal... and btw, has nothing to do with the compiler

Comment: What did you expect to see? Note that there is no "syntactic symmetry" to `&` in the way that there is for `*`.

Answer (score 5):

> I don't know what it is?

`cout<< &refVal<<endl;` you are printing the address of `refVal` (which is the address of `ival`).

> Please also elaborate if you feel i am lacking some basic/very important knowledge here!

You are confusing references with pointers and `&` has two different meanings:

Declaration of reference:

```
 int& refVal = ival;
 // ^ part of the type
```

Address-of operator:

```
 int* refPtr = &refVal;
             //^ address-of operator
```

Frankly, yes this is both basic and very important, it should be covered in the first chapters of an introductory book.

To print the value of `ival` via the reference `refVal`:

```
std::cout << refVal;
```

Note that there is no special syntax to "dereference the reference". A reference is like an alias, a different name for the same object.